# Who is the man in Daniel's vision in Daniel 10?

Tags: prophecy, daniel

Who does Daniel see in his vision in [Daniel 10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010&version=NIV1984)?

Answer (score 14):

**Could it have been Jesus?**

I doubt it could be Jesus, because the implication of [verses 12-13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010:12-13&version=NIV) is that the speaker was restrained by the *"prince of the Persian kingdom"*; I doubt the prince could have restrained Jesus.

**So is it an angel or a human?**

[Verses 5-6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010:5-6&version=NIV) show that the person is an angel:

> I looked up and there before me was a man dressed in linen, with a belt of fine gold from Uphaz around his waist. His body was like topaz, his face like lightning, his eyes like flaming torches, his arms and legs like the gleam of burnished bronze, and his voice like the sound of a multitude.

**Can we know the identity of the angel?**

There are only two named angels in the Bible, [Michael](http://www.biblegateway.com/keyword/?search=Michael&version1=NIV&searchtype=all&limit=none&wholewordsonly=no)<sup>1</sup> and [Gabriel](http://www.biblegateway.com/keyword/?search=Gabriel&searchtype=all&version1=31&language1=en&spanbegin=1&spanend=73).

It cannot have been Michael, because the speaker refers to him (in [verses 13 & 21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010:13,21&version=NIV)).

So it must be either Gabriel or an unnamed angel. However, Daniel recognised Gabriel when he appeared in a previous vision: [Daniel 9:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%209:21&version=NIV1984):

> ...while I was still in prayer, **Gabriel**, the man I had seen in the earlier vision, came to me in swift flight about the time of the evening sacrifice.

Since he does not recognise Gabriel this time, it is also not likely to be him. Therefore my conclusion is: **it is an unnamed angel**.

<sub>1 List includes other Biblical characters also named Michael.</sub>

Comment: What is your rationale for stating definitively that v.5-6 describe an angel?

Comment: @Schuh: what else could a being of that description be?

Comment: Apocalyptic visions are full of all kinds of colorful characters and images: natural, supernatural, literary, metaphorical and allegorical.  This one isn't like anything we're met before.  What's the *evidence* that it's an angel?

Comment: @Schuh I agree that he is describing an Angel since the Bible does not talk of aliens , ewoks or Jedi. But pray tell us... in your opinion what or who do you think Daniel saw if it not be an angel of Jehovah?

Comment: @Dr.Apell, I’m suggesting a conservative hermeneutic.  Perhaps the author didn’t provide enough detail for a definitive identification, but the clues should at least be fully examined (eg. lightning, Upgaz gold, topaz, burnished bronze). In apocalyptic stories all the details are meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

Although many sources claim otherwise, it is clear after examining the scripture, that the man whom Daniel encounters is NOT Jesus Christ. When people compare Daniel's vision of this angel to the similarity of John's vision of Christ in Revelation they do not seem to take notice of the differences in the details of their descriptions.

1. Revelation 1:13 describes Christ "dressed in a robe reaching down to His feet", whereas Daniel 10:6 clearly states that he was able to see the man's "arms and legs like the gleam of burnished bronze". Christ is not dressed in a manner which exposes that much of His body. In fact, Revelation 1:15 states that the only visible part of Christ's legs were His feet, which "were like bronze glowing in a furnace". On top of that, the word "burnished" indicates a finished work, and means shining, polished bronze. However, John's description of Christ's feet "glowing in a furnace" indicates that He is still directly connected to the heat source of the Creator—God the Father, the "Master Craftsman"--and is therefore, emitting the intense heat and brightness of an object still in a metal smith's hands within a furnace.
2. Daniel 10:6 clearly states that the man had "a *belt* of finest gold around his **waist**", whereas Christ is described in Revelation 1:13 with a "golden *sash* around His **chest**".
3. The next undeniable difference is that the man in Daniel's vision had a "voice like the sound of a multitude" (Dan 10:6), this word is used over and over in the bible to refer to a great number of "something".

   As in:

   > "Judah and Israel were as numerous as the sand by the sea in **multitude**, eating and drinking and rejoicing." (1 Kings 4:20)
   >
   > "So when Judah came to a place overlooking the wilderness, they looked toward the **multitude**; and there were their dead bodies, fallen on the earth. No one had escaped." (2 Chronicles 20:24)
   >
   > "Those who trust in their wealth And boast in the **multitude** of their riches," (Psalm 49:6)

   The word multitude, however is most often used--when not followed by an object--to a refer to a multitude of people.

   As in:

   > "And now you think to withstand the kingdom of the Lord, which is in the hand of the sons of David; and you are a great **multitude**, and with you are the gold calves which Jeroboam made for you as gods." (2 Chronicles 13:8)
   >
   > “Son of man, say to Pharaoh king of Egypt and to his **multitude**: ‘Whom are you like in your greatness?" (Ezekiel 31:2)

   Therefore, it can be safely assumed that Daniel meant when the angel spoke his voice was like that of a great number of people. In comparison, Revelation 1:15 John clearly states that Christ had a voice like "the sound of rushing waters", this is clearly a very different voice than the one heard by Daniel.
4. Lastly, although there is a similarity in the way the faces of both Christ and Daniel's vision are described, it is undeniable that the description of Christ yields a more intense picture than that of the angel described by Daniel. John describes Christ's face like "the sun shining in all its brilliance" (Revelation 1:16), but Daniel describes the face of his vision as definitively having a "face like lightning". Lightning can be viewed with the naked eye, but the sun shining in all its brilliance arguably can't even be seen without causing damage to one's eyesight. Daniel also describes his vision as having "eyes like flaming torches" versus John's description of Christ in Revelation 1:14 as having "eyes like blazing fire". A blazing torch, paints a picture of a fire *contained*, whereas a blazing fire, indicates a flame that is *unconstrained* and can spread. A fitting picture of the light of our Lord Jesus.

#### The Differences Outlined

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║             ║ MAN IN DANIEL 10:6             ║ CHRIST IN REVELATION 1:13-15          ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ CLOTHING    ║ short linen garment            ║ long robe reaching to his feet        ║
║             ║ (arms/legs exposed)            ║ (only hands/feet exposed)             ║
║             ║                                ║                                       ║
║ BODY        ║ arms/legs burnished bronze     ║ feet, bronze glowing in a furnace     ║
║             ║ (polished, indicates finished, ║ (still heated, very hot/bright)       ║
║             ║ shining work)                  ║                                       ║
║             ║                                ║                                       ║
║ ACCESSORIES ║ golden belt around waist       ║ golden sash around chest              ║
║             ║                                ║                                       ║
║ VOICE       ║ sound of a multitude (people)  ║ sound of rushing waters               ║
║             ║                                ║                                       ║
║ FACE        ║ like lightning                 ║ the sun shining in all its brilliance ║
║             ║                                ║                                       ║
║ EYES        ║ blazing torches                ║ blazing fire                          ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

#### Conclusion

It was an angel that Daniel witnessed, most likely of a high order, because the other two angels that appear on either side of him, inquire of his knowledge in Daniel 12:5-6. John's vision of Christ dwarfs Daniel's vision when compared in intensity, and it is imperative to understand that when Daniel saw his vision he *stood* "gazing at this great vision" although he "had no strength left" and his "face turned deathly pale" and "was helpless". He also "fell *into a deep sleep* [his] face to the ground", when he "listened to him" (Daniel 10:8-9). Whereas when John saw Christ, "he fell at his feet **as though dead**" (Revelation 1:17). This difference in reaction **must** not be ignored. Daniel was able to stand before his vision, and although he felt helpless and turned pale, it was not until the vision spoke that his body was taken into a state of "deep sleep" with his "face to the ground". Make no mistake, John "fell down as though dead" at the *very sight* of Christ. Daniel, did *not* see Christ, or his reaction would no doubt have been exactly the same upon merely viewing this being.

Comment: Can you correlate this person in Daniel 10 with the fourth person, whom Nebuchadnezzar had noticed was in the fire with Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego in Daniel 3? Is he the protector of the faithful remnant of Israel? Who might that person be according to The Revelation of John?

Comment: Isa 60:5

*Then you shall see and be radiant;
your heart shall thrill and exult because the **abundance** of the sea shall be turned to you,

* Jer 10:13

*When he utters his voice, there is a **tumult** of waters in the heavens,
and he makes the mist rise from the ends of the earth.* Those are the same word for multitude. It actually fits perfect with the "sound like many waters" of Ezekiel, which Revelation 1 then picks up on. I'm sorry, but I see 4-5 direct *similarities*, not differences, in your chart. The robe is the only thing and that seems a bit small.

Comment: You present (almost) equal things as if they were opposites.

Answer (score 1):

Some have taken this vision to be an angel (Lange’s Commentary, Moses Stuart, Calvin, etc.). On the contrary, **I think we can conclusively state that ‘yes’ this is the Son of God, at least as understood by New Testament writers.** The similarity between this vision and that by John’s vision in Rev Chapter 1 makes it very hard not to draw any other conclusion. Naturally, many commentators have therefore taken this view (Keil, Matthew Henry, Alexander Arthur, E. B. Elliot, etc.).

For example, the German and always so conservative scholar Keil takes this view:

> This heavenly form has thus, it is true, the shining white talar common to the angel, Ezek. 9:9, but all the other features, as here described—the shining of his body, the brightness of his countenance, his eyes like a lamp of fire, arms and feet like glistering brass, the sound of his speaking—all these point to the revelation of the כְּבֹוד יְהֹוָה, the glorious appearance of the Lord, Ezek. 1, and teach us that the אִישׁ seen by Daniel was no common angel-prince, but a manifestation of Jehovah, i.e., the Logos. This is placed beyond a doubt by a comparison with Rev. 1:13–15, where the form of the Son of man whom John saw walking in the midst of the seven golden candlesticks is described like the glorious appearance seen by Ezekiel and Daniel. (Keil, C. F., & Delitzsch, F. (1996). Commentary on the Old Testament (Vol. 9, p. 766). Peabody, MA: Hendrickson.)

One of the best classic commentaries written on Daniel takes this view and adds:

> His hovering on the water of the river reminds me of him who walked on the Sea of Galilee; and his two attendant angels remind me of him who talked with Abraham, and sent his two attendants to destroy Sodom and Gomorrah. If I am mistaken in the pictures, I am willing to hug my own delusion. (A critical Commentary on the Book of Daniel, by Alexander Arthur, Page 190, 1893)

I think the key point to consider is that although the one described in Daniel 10:4-6 is Christ, starting at verse 10 where ‘a hand’ touches him it is not the person of the vision but an angel who is involved in communicating the meaning of the vision of Christ. This is probably what causes some commentaries to go astray and miss the obvious similitude to Rev Chapter 1.

Alexander Arthur again to me follows a persuasive position:

> 1. Is the speaker all along the man clothed in linen? I think not. 2. Are these so-called princes, as Jerome has taught, the guardian angels of different countries, holy angels who fight with one another? Again, I think not. 1. This man clothed in linen is again mentioned only in the 12th chapter, ver. 6, and there he is upon the waters of the river, like Jesus walking on the sea ; but we are not told where he was in the eleventh chapter. (A critical Commentary on the Bok of Daniel, by Alexander Arthur, Page 193, 1893)

Having chosen again the view of ‘an angel’, it should be noted that in precise language many take this to be an angel of sorts that is the ‘Angel Jehovah’ who is often considered by many commentators the pre-human visitation of the Son of God, i.e. the logos. But the angel in this sense is not to be confused with a mere angel, but the Son of God. E. B. Elliot in his classic four volume commentary of Revelation makes this distinction in reference to Daniel Chapter 10. Commenting on Rev 10:5-7 Elliot says:

> Here, besides the obvious similarity in respect of the terms and manner of the oath, as lifting up his hand to heaven, and swearing by Him that liveth for ever, it is evident from the context that He who used it was the Angel Jehovah, just as in the Apocalyptic vision under consideration. [On his first appearance to Daniel, he is thus described. “As I was by the side of the great river Hiddekel, I lifted up mine eyes, and looked. And behold a certain man clothed in linen, whose loins were girded with fine gold of Uphaz! His body also was like the beryl, and his face as the appearance of lightning, and his eyes as lamps of fire, and his feet like in colour to polished brass, and the voice of his words as the voice of a multitude.” Dan. 10:4–6. Comparing this with the description of Christ in the 1st of the Apocalypse, the correspondence seems such as almost necessarily to involve identity]. (Elliott, E. B. (1862). Horæ Apocalypticæ or A Commentary on the Apocalypse, Critical and Historical, Volume 2)

Answer (score -1):

There are total 4 persons mentioned from Daniel 10:5 till Daniel 12:5-7.

1. **Jesus Christ:** The person Daniel saw in chapter 10:5-6 is definitely Jesus Christ - 5: **there was a certain man dressed in linen**...6: **his face had the appearance of lightning** and the rest of the men **could not** see the vision and ran away in fear... This is similar to Pauls divine encounter with Jesus  Acts 9:7 - **And the men which journeyed with him stood speechless, hearing a voice, but seeing no man**.
2. **Angel:** 10 - Then behold, a hand touched me and set me trembling on my hands and knees. 18 Then this one with **human appearance** touched me again and strengthened me. 
   The prince of persia held this **angel** for 21 days.
3. **2 other angels** are mentioned in Chapter 12:5, and in 12:6 -  And one said to the **man dressed in linen**, **who was above the waters of the river**, "How long will it be until the end of these wonders?" 12:7 I heard the **man dressed in linen**, **who was above the waters of the river**, **as he raised his right hand and his left toward heaven, and swore by Him who lives forever**...

This person was again Jesus Christ signified by 1. linen, 2. hovering over waters, 3. standing away from Daniel as Daniel was on land as he fell on the ground when he first saw Jesus (10:9) and 4. His swearing by God the Father with the authority of His Son.

Answer (score -2):

Id like to put forward that the slight differences in description of the glorious man in Daniel and the description of Jesus in Revelation, and the fact that Daniels glorious man had to fight the "prince of the Persian kingdom" could be because Jesus had not been glorified and yet to destroy the works of the devil by going to the cross (where all victory is won). Where as with John, Jesus carries a whole new level of authority and glory... Just something to think about... I swing towards believing that the description in Daniel is too similar to the description of Christ in Revelation. But we all see dimly don't we :)

Comment: I'm very grateful for your participation here, but [this site is a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423). You may want to provide some explanation and context. Don't just give an opinion-based response; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. I think you can benefit a lot if you see the [kind of answers](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/520/3474) that this site is looking for.
Be sure to visit the [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site.